# Unable to stream YouTube Url in VLC android

Tags: android, youtube, stream, android-mediaplayer, vlc

I have already integrated VLC player in my android app in Linux environment.But now the issue is when i try to play the YouTube link .It Unable to stream the YouTube URL and the concerned g-data ".3gp" URL.The error is mentioned below.

"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq1gNicFkeM can not be played." in Toast.

Does anyone have any idea on the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC for Android does not support the lua plugins needed to parse the YT URL.

You need to parse the HTML layout yourself (and feed the resulting URL to VLC) or add support for lua plugins to VLC for Android to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a temporary solution.I'm not an expert, but this did the trick for me:

1. Find a website which can download youtube video's (I suggest keepvid.com)
2. Paste the url of your youtube video into the designated bar and, although we are not downloading anything, hit the Download button.
3. Now the website gives you a list with different formats for you to choose from. RIGHT-click the one on top (mp4?) and copy the link's adress.

This link can be played in VLC Android and includes your youtube video.

Comment: we're talking about programming here, so everything should be done automatically